# What version of Rhino JavaScript does Salesforce Commerce Cloud use?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, rhino, demandware

As I understand it Salesforce CommerceCloud uses [Rhino JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino), but sadly I cannot find what version it is, which is important for understanding [compatibility](https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html). Is there any documentation that describes this, and/or is there a way to output the JavaScript engine version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Rhino 1.7R5**

I was pointed to an answer on [GitHub SFCC community docs FAQ](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/community-docs/blob/master/frequently-asked-questions.md#what-rhino-version-does-salesforce-b2c-commerce-use) *(requires login)*, which cited an official post on a forum from 2016:

> ... the supported language dialect Demandware Javascript is Rhino Javascript (currently Rhino release 1.7R5) ...

Comment: And if you're curious what is supported in Rhino, this is very useful: https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html

Answer (score 0):

If the product allows you to execute JavaScript code directly, there are (probably, unless they've configured it in particular ways, e.g., with `ClassShutter` to disable script access to certain Java classes) ways to get at the Rhino version. The following will return the version as a `java.lang.String`:

```
Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext().getImplementationVersion()
```

You can convert this to a JavaScript string using the `String` global function:

```
var jlsVersion = Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext().getImplementationVersion();
var jsStringVersion = String(jlsVersion);
```

**EDIT**: *Poster points out this is a cloud service, not a local installation, so `js.jar` is not available, and the below method won't help. I'm leaving this this answer up because it may be relevant to others who find this questtion through search.*

Assuming they distribute the Rhino JAR file (ordinarily called `js.jar`), and you can locate it, you can also just execute it (and it will output the version and take you to an interactive JavaScript prompt). Here's a copy on my machine (outside Salesforce):

```
$ java -jar js.jar
Rhino 1.7 release 3 2011 05 09
js>
```

Comment: Since SFCC is a cloud-based service I don't know of a way to locate or execute this JAR file.

Comment: If it allows you to execute JavaScript code, there are also ways to get at the version directly. Does it?

Comment: I updated the answer above to account for that possibility.

Comment: I know it's been almost a year but: in the SFCC environment `Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext` appears as an object, not a function (with string value `"[JavaPackage org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext]"`). `Object.keys()` on it reveals the following non-sense structure: `{ "__iterator__": { "__iterator__": {} } }`

Comment: That means the class is not present; it is assuming the string given is a package name (this is an unfortunate consequence of how the `Packages` construct works).

Comment: I would guess that either it is not using Rhino, is using a private build that renames the classes, or is using the stock Rhino that came with the JDK 6 and JDK 7 distributions (replaced by Nashorn in JDK 8).